# proper way to communicate between more than two processes in pyqt5 python

Tags: python, pyqt5, multiprocessing

I currently have two processes, one is my pyqt5 MainWindow (parent process) and a child process. I mainly use Pipe to communicate between the two. As per my research, a Pipe can have only two end-points which in my case, it has already been given to the two end-points above. But I now am in need of a temporary third/brother process which is created when a user click on pyqt5 button any time. The brother process needs to send pyqtSignal to parent process for result output.

Why not use threads? 1. I don't want the child thread to access parent thread's memory. 2. there is no direct way to abruptly kill a thread unless using `try & except` method, which I cannot use. Hence, I need to use multiprocessing.

Can anyone tell me If I need a third pipe for my brother process, if so, how do I implement it to my pyqt5 application. Reproducible code is below.

Code **main.py**:

```
import os
import sys
import PyQt5
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Pipe
from untitled import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QObject, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem, QIcon
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Pipe
import time

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("."))

class Emitter(QThread):
    pcLBL = pyqtSignal(str)
    
    def __init__(self, from_process: Pipe):
        super().__init__()
        self.data_from_process = from_process
    

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                sd = self.data_from_process.recv()
            except EOFError:
                break
            else:
                if(len(sd) > 1 and sd[0] == "pcLBL"):
                    self.pcLBL.emit(sd[1])


class childProc(Process):
    def __init__(self, to_emitter: Pipe, from_mother: Queue, daemon=True):
        super().__init__()
        self.daemon = daemon
        self.to_emitter = to_emitter
        self.data_from_mother = from_mother

    def run(self):
        i = 0
        while(True):
            print("talking to mommy")
            self.to_emitter.send(["pcLBL", "Yollo mommy, I am your first child "+str(i)])
            i += 1
            time.sleep(10)
            
            
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, child_process_queue: Queue, emitter: Emitter):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.process_queue = child_process_queue
        self.emitter = emitter
        self.emitter.daemon = True
        self.emitter.start()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.mainCode()

    def mainCode(self):
        self.someBTN.clicked.connect(self.testFunc)
        self.emitter.pcLBL.connect(self.pcLBL.setText)
        
    def testFunc(self):
        files = ["c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe"]
        mother_pipe, child_pipe = Pipe()
        queue = Queue()
        emitter = Emitter(mother_pipe)
        broProc = brotherProc(files[0], child_pipe, self.process_queue)
        broProc.start()

class brotherProc(Process):
    def __init__(self, files, to_emitter: Pipe, from_mother: Queue, daemon=True):
        super().__init__()
        self.daemon = daemon
        self.to_emitter = to_emitter
        self.data_from_mother = from_mother
        self.files = files

    def run(self):
        print("started")
        doStuff(self.to_emitter, self.files, 2)

def doStuff(signaller, file, num):
    signaller.send(["pcLBL", "Hello mother"])


def pickleChildProc(child_pipe, queue):
    cp = childProc(child_pipe, queue)
    cp.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    mother_pipe, child_pipe = Pipe()
    queue = Queue()
    emitter = Emitter(mother_pipe)
    childProc = pickleChildProc(child_pipe, queue)

    Dialog = MainWindow(queue, emitter)

    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**pyqt5Main.py:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.someBTN = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.someBTN.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 260, 251, 23))
        self.someBTN.setObjectName("someBTN")
        self.pcLBL = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.pcLBL.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 350, 731, 20))
        self.pcLBL.setObjectName("pcLBL")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.someBTN.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Create Process"))
        self.pcLBL.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Show results here"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

With above on line `signaller.send(["pcLBL", "Hello mother process"])` in the brother process, I get `BrokenPipeError: [WinError 232] The pipe is being closed`.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue, probably because I had to fix some portions of code that you left incomplete, so I suggest you to provide a valid [mre]. Also, can you be more precise about your reason for not using threads?

Comment: @musicamante, updated my code to one which is fully reproducible above.

Comment: I may have an answer, but since I'm not on Windows I cannot be 100% sure: try changing to `self.pipe = mother_pipe, child_pipe = Pipe()` in `testFunc()`. Also, please answer my other question too, because unless you *specifically* need the benefits (and complications) of multiprocessing, it might not be worth it.

Comment: @musicamante I don't understand what you mean by `self.pipe = mother_pipe, child_pipe = Pipe()`. Are there meant to be two '='? have never seen that before. When I did that, I get `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'send'` on line `signaller.send(["pcLBL", "Hello mother"])`

Comment: Please, follow my instruction more carefully: you only need to change **that** line, don't use `self.pipe` as argument of `brotherProc()`. And, yes, it's called "chained assignment": `a = b = 2` is the same as `a = 2; b = 2` or `b = 2; a = b`, and it also works for iterable objects: `a, b = c = [0, 1]` is like `c = [0, 1]; a, b = c`.

Comment: @musicamante, I did as you said, I changed only that one line, Now I don't get any errors, but the `pcLBL` doesn't update as well. Thank very much for your help BTW.

Comment: I do see my print output `started` in brotherProc.run function after the line change.

Comment: It's quite strange that *now* it doesn't get errors, since what you reported could have only happened if you used the whole tuple as argument, or you are testing on a different code: you *are* using the code of your question, aren't you? Because we can only provide answers based on the code you provide, if you're testing on a *different* code and apply changes improperly, we cannot know that and we cann't help you with it. So, *first* try the suggestions based on the above code, *then*, if it works, try to apply it to your actual code. I'm still waiting for an answer to my other question, btw.

Comment: @musicamante, I am testing on the code above, I also have provided the answer to why not use thread in my question update. `testFunc()` now looks like: `def testFunc(self):
        files = ["c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe"]
        self.pipe = mother_pipe, child_pipe = Pipe()
        queue = Queue()
        emitter = Emitter(mother_pipe)
        broProc = brotherProc(files[0], child_pipe, self.process_queue)
        broProc.start()`

Comment: Sorry, but that explanation is too vague: 1. why you don't want to share the memory? 2. there are a lot of ways to properly **exit** a thread (instead of abruptly killing, which should be an extreme condition) that all depend on what the thread does, and without knowing what you actually do there we cannot really help you. That said, try to make the other objects in that function as instance attributes (which is what I believe being the main issue of your code). Also, you should really be more careful about object purpose and naming. For instance, you're overwriting `childProc`.

Comment: @musicamante would you know what the problem with above is?

Comment: I've already said that I'm not on Windows, so you need to understand that I can only work based on your replies, which means that you **must** ensure that you're properly applying changes as suggested and provide appropriate context to your answers. Yet, I still strongly believe you're using mp for the wrong reasons (or, at least, you've not provided a **valid** reason for it). If you want help, please answer what is being requested and ensure that the answer is appropriate. There's absolutely no point in trying to fix some code that could possibly have no reason to exist in the first place.